# How to recover an Android Studio project written in Kotlin from the apk

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, recovery

I've finished the work on my Android app. for my university, and I havn't backed it up to git for 11 days because I've had no internet on my PC. I bought an SSD today, and amidst the data transfers, I'd somehow managed to delete my entire project (along with a whole semester's woth of work).
I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file) post but it's for a project writen in Java. Is there a way to recover a project writen in Kotlin from the application's apk.?

Comment: You could decompile to Java and then convert the files to Kotlin in Android Studio's conversion feature. But the code won't look like what you originally wrote. All comments will be gone, and inline function calls will actually be inlined among other sorts of optimizations the compiler may have made, so readability of your code will probably be poor.